# Why does a iPhone better than Galaxy?

Tags: iphone, ios, android

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 and I consider to buy iPhone 5S.
What are the advantages of iPhone relatively to Galaxy?

Comment: This is *subjective*. There are many great things about the iPhone 5/iOS, but there are as many great things about the Samsung Galaxy/Android.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is subjective and has no canonical answer. Personal preference plays too large a role in answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone combines software and hardware that both designed by Apple which drives to better performance.

iPhone's body is aluminum compared to plastic of the Galaxy s4.

iPhone running iOS, personally I think it's a better OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an Android vs. iPhone argument is really appropriate here… but what do I know? :D

It seems the majority of the best apps come to iOS first, others second, if at all. Also, this is a pretty good reason: http://www.tomsguide.com/us/android-flaw-trifecta,news-17976.html *Android Security-Flaw Trifecta Threatens Smartphones, Tablets*. Apple's ecosystem may be more locked-down and restricted, but it certainly appears to have better security.